# Как сделать смену материала на сайте, не переходя на другую страницу?

Tags: веб-программирование

Как сделать смену материала на сайте, не переходя на другую страницу. Вот как здесь - [devanswers](http://devanswers.ru/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрим код на сайте и гуглим

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
....
```

JavaScript: Проще - с его отдельной библиотекой JQuery.